# What those F# functions are supposed to do?

Tags: f#

Learning F# these days, I've noticed that in some libraries like [this one](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Extras/ComputationExpressions/Result.fs) or [that one](https://github.com/fsprojects/Chessie/blob/master/src/Chessie/ErrorHandling.fs)
there are some similar functions which seem to be common in F# but can't really decipher them, what are they doing, what are they for?

```ml
let ap x f =
    match f, x with
    | Ok f        , Ok x    -> Ok (f x)
    | Error e     , _       -> Error e
    | _           , Error e -> Error e
let inline (<*>) f x = ap x f
let inline (<!>) f x = Result.map f x
let inline lift2 f a b = f <!> a <*> b
```

Even aggregating comments with them does not really help in my understanding:

```ml
/// Sequential application
/// If the wrapped function is a success and the given result is a success the function is applied on the value. 
/// Otherwise the exisiting error messages are propagated.
let ap x f =
match f,x with
    | Ok f        , Ok x    -> Ok (f x)
    | Error e     , _       -> Error e
    | _           , Error e -> Error e

/// Sequential application
/// If the wrapped function is a success and the given result is a success the function is applied on the value. 
/// Otherwise the exisiting error messages are propagated.
let inline (<*>) f x = ap x f

/// Infix map, lifts a function into a Result and applies it on the given result.
let inline (<!>) f x = Result.map f x

/// Promote a function to a monad/applicative, scanning the monadic/applicative arguments from left to right.
let inline lift2 f a b = f <!> a <*> b
```

I don't even see an example of how they could be used, not sure also why `inline` has been used.

If there is somebody who could hint about how useful those functions are, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: You got good answers already but I just wanted to mention they are thinking about extending computation expression to support applicative functors (because they are awesome!): https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1063-support-letbang-andbang-for-applicative-functors.md

Comment: inline probably to remove a level of indirection and thus potentially gain a performance benefit. The other use case for inline is if you need type constraints not support by .NET

Comment: Just for the record - I'd say those are fairly advanced things that might sometimes be useful, but I would not worry about them when learning F#.  It's an interesting fact that there is a common pattern here, but I don't think I ever actually needed these in my own F# projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called "applicative functors" (sometimes just "applicatives"). Their purpose is to combine data from multiple `Something<'T>` using a function. Basically, "lifting" a function of type `'Arg1 -> 'Arg2 -> ... -> 'Result` into a function of type `Something<'Arg1> -> Something<'Arg2> -> ... -> Something<'Result>`.

For example, given the standard Result type:

```
type Result<'T, 'Err> = Ok of 'T | Error of 'Err
```

you may have several Result values that you want to combine together. For example, say you have a form with inputs firstName, lastName and age. You also have a result type `Person`:

```
type Person = { firstName: string; lastName: string; age: int }

// string -> string -> int -> Person
let makePerson firstName lastName age =
    { firstName = firstName; lastName = lastName; age = age }
```

The values coming from your actual form may have type `Result<string, InputError>` or `Result<int, InputError>`, which can be `Error` if eg. the user hasn't entered a value.

```
type InputError =
    | FieldMissing of fieldName: string
    // Other error cases...
```

You want to combine them into a `Result<Person, InputError>`, which is `Ok` if all inputs are `Ok`, or `Error` if any input is `Error`. Using the applicative, you can do it like this:

```
// Result<string, InputError> -> Result<string, InputError> -> Result<int, InputError> -> Result<Person, InputError>
let makePersonResult firstName lastName age =
    makePerson <!> firstName <*> lastName <*> age

// Example uses:

makePersonResult (Ok "John") (Ok "Doe") (Ok 42)
// --> Ok { firstName = "John"; lastName = "Doe"; age = 42 }
makePersonResult (Error (FieldMissing "firstName")) (Ok "Doe") (Ok 42)
// --> Error (FieldMissing "firstName")
```

A similar concept can be applied to many other types than Result, which is why it was given a name. For example, an applicative on `Async<'T>` could run all the argument Asyncs in parallel, and when they're finished, combine their results into an `Async<'Result>`. Another example, an applicative on `'T list` would be equivalent to the standard library's `List.map2` or `List.map3` but generalizable to any number of argument lists.

Side note: if you look up "applicative functor", most of the results you'll find will be in Haskell, where the map operator, usually written `<!>` in F#, is written `<$>` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Scott Wlaschin's *F# for fun and profit* (https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com) has a series *Map and Bind and Apply, Oh my!* (https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-7) which should be able to shed more light on this. Regarding your particular question:

- `<!>` is the `map` operator which applies a function `f` and a parameter `x` to elements of the data structure you are mapping over, or in other words, lifts the function into the realm of the data structure, in this case the `Result` type.
- `<*>` is the `ap` (apply) operator which unpacks a function wrapped inside a elevated value into a lifted function.
- `lift2` is basically the `map` operator for a two-parameter function.

Please have a look at the blog, it really helps!